# 'at', 'on' or 'from' social media in specific sentence

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have to make a poster to promote my projects and I'm really confused about which preposition to put there: the sentence looks like this:

> Don't miss the latest news **at (on)** our social media.

Which preposition are appropriate to use from these ones: **at**, **on**, or even **from**?

Comment: *In (social) media* has far more  popularity than *on* or *at* (social) media, as per Neram viewer. {https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+media%2Con+media%2C+at+media&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20media%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20media%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20media%3B%2Cc0}

Comment: I was very surprised by the result of the [Ngram 2000 to 2008](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+social+media%2Con+social+media%2Cat+social+media&year_start=2000&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20social%20media%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20social%20media%3B%2Cc0) 'on social media' against 'in social media'. I was expecting 'on' to prevail. 'At/from' have no mention at all. I have always heard 'on social media', but the result says BrE is exclusively 'in'.

Comment: @mahmudkoya Ngramming 'in media/on media' doesn't tell me what 'social media' is doing, preposition-wise.